# JSON and dynamic TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

Can anyone provide me with any good example of JSON string to clickable tableview?

I am getting json string with tasks from server (already working) and i need to post it view with tableview. BUT it should be able to click and give that line's message. Json structure:

```
{ "messages":[{  
   "id": ....,  
   "msg":....,  
   "special":...,  
   "comments":...}]}
```

Any good examples?

Comment: i dont understad ,you want to populate your tableview with json value?

Comment: i want to parse json value to diferent table lines. And by pressing table line to alert a message of that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this video really usefull for learning.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MEnvlqP-wU

Also check some of my questions I ask alot about JSON but videos are a good way to move forward.

More Links :)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YggsvQC2SH0

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k

Comment: I have a stupid question. Will this work on iphone 4.2 version? :)

Comment: yeah it depends, if you need help just post your code and others will help and explain. If this helpyed you please mark correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for what your are trying to do. You can modify to be viewable in differently if you want, let me if this is correct or is there some other way you were looking to display the messages.

```
//
//  MyViewController.h
//  Test
//
//  Created by Syed Arsalan Pervez on 2/22/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SAPLogix. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *_messages;
}

@end



//
//  MyViewController.m
//  Test
//
//  Created by Syed Arsalan Pervez on 2/22/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SAPLogix. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *JSONString = @"{\"messages\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"msg\":\"Message Line\",\"special\":\"Special Line\",\"comments\":\"Comments Line\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"msg\":\"Message Line\",\"special\":\"Special Line\",\"comments\":\"Comments Line\"}]}";

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *JSONObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {
        _messages = [[JSONObj valueForKey:@"messages"] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [_messages count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *_message = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [_message valueForKey:@"msg"];
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [_message valueForKey:@"special"];
            break;

        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = [_message valueForKey:@"comments"];
            break;
    }
    _message = nil;

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *_message = [_messages objectAtIndex:section];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message %@", [_message valueForKey:@"id"]];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *_message = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString new];
    [string appendFormat:@"Message %@: ", [_message valueForKey:@"id"]];
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            [string appendString:[_message valueForKey:@"msg"]];
            break;

        case 1:
            [string appendString:[_message valueForKey:@"special"]];
            break;

        case 2:
            [string appendString:[_message valueForKey:@"comments"]];
            break;
    }
    _message = nil;

    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:string delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
    [string release];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_messages release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to parse that JSON response using library , like [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework),and then create array or dictionary from your data and use this dictionary and array to populate your tableview.

If you can provide your json response than I can help you to parse it.

i am addind some code snippet that show parsing:

```
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];


            //to display driver name in drop down

            NSArray * messagesArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
            messagesArray= [jsonData objectForKey:@"messages"];


            for(int i=0;i<[driverNameArray count];i++)
            {
                NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
                if([tempDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]!=nil)
                {

                    [idAry addObject:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];

                }
                if([tempDictionary objectForKey:@"msg"]!=nil)
                {

                    [msgAry addObject:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"msg"]];

                }
                if([tempDictionary objectForKey:@"special"]!=nil)
                {

                    [specialAry addObject:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"special"]];

                }
                if([tempDictionary objectForKey:@"comments"]!=nil)
                {

                    [commentsAry addObject:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"comments"]];

                }

            }
```

the all array that i have used commentsAry,specialAry,msgAry,idAry hold your data ,and can be used to populate tableview.

Comment: i have provided you the return of JSON. "..." means what it can return (depends on what is in datanase). first is like id:1, msg:test,special:0,comments:0

Comment: You code has so many leaks even if you are using ARC try an avoid useless alloc.

Comment: @SAPLogix its not useless alloc.

Comment: @Dilip 
NSArray * messagesArray = [[NSArray alloc]init]; // assigns memory 
messagesArray= [jsonData objectForKey:@"messages"]; // assign that pointer to a different location 
So the memory perviously assigned is not used and is a useless allocation.

Comment: @SAPLogix if you not going to alloc that array than you got error that unallocated array used,i have tried it.

Comment: @Dilip That is because your code has no checks, you are not checking if the messagesArray = [jsonData objectForKey:@"messages"]; actually sets the array or not. Without checking you are using it in for loop so you are bound to get errors.